# Better method of connecting spark streamming, sockets and rabbitMQ

Tags: python, sockets, apache-spark, spark-streaming

To get around the trouble of consuming rabbit messages directly in spark streaming, I decided to consume messages using pika (python adaptor) and send them using sockets with the aim of getting spark streaming to communicate with the send data via sockets. However, I seem not to be able to hook up all three. For example:

```
RabbitMQ producer -> RabbitMQ consumer -> Socket Message -> Spark Streaming
```

I can get the messages received from RabbitMQ and sent to Socket, but I cannot listen from Spark Streaming - I get the following:

```
ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Restarting receiver with delay 2000ms: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:5005 - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Now I use `ncat -l -p 5005` as simple intermediary. I can get a simple service running. But it seems that the Spark and the Rabbit Receiver interfere, as I can run ncat and spark streaming without error, but then I cannot run my RabbitMQ consumer code and I get the following error from this service:

```
self._connection = self.connect()
  File "socketsend.py", line 93, in connect
    self.sandwich = Sandwich() # connect up the bridge between the Rabbit World and Spark
  File "socketsend.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.s.connect( (self.TCP_IP, self.TCP_PORT) )          
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

So in summary of order ncat, RabbitConsumer -> RabbitConsumer fails
or I do ncat, RabbitConsumer, Spark -> Spark fails

Here are some code extracts for sending message from rabbitconsumer.py:

```
class Sandwich(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
        self.TCP_PORT = 5005
        self.BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.connect( (self.TCP_IP, self.TCP_PORT) )          


    def SendDirectTCP(self, body):  
        self.s.send(body)
        return "done"
```

and Sandwich is called on `__init__` of standard Pika, boiler place consumer and SendDirectTCP is called on `on_message`.

The test spark streaming code is:

```
import sys
import operator
import json

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext


sc = SparkContext(appName="SS")
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")

lines = ssc.socketTextStream("127.0.0.1", 5005)
words = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
pairs = words.map(lambda word: (word, 1))
wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
wordCounts.pprint()


ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
ssc.stop()
```